# ImportError: cannot import name 'builder' from 'google.protobuf.internal'

Tags: python

I am following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDXdlXlaCco&t=1520s). At 22:22, an error was found in this code:

```
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + '/train'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x{IMAGE_PATH + '/test'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record'}
```

Post exact error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\info\1 Master\2 semster\RealTimeObjectDetection-main\Tensorflow\scripts\generate_tfrecord.py", line 29, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import dataset_util, label_map_util
  File "C:\Users\bachir\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 29, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
  File "C:\Users\bachir\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\object_detection\protos\string_int_label_map_pb2.py", line 5, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.internal import builder as _builder
ImportError: cannot import name 'builder' from 'google.protobuf.internal' (C:\Users\bachir\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\__init__.py)
```

First I tried to download some missing packages but same problem, I would like to help

Answer (score 107):

Follow these steps:

1. Install the latest protobuf version (in my case is 4.21.1)

> `pip install --upgrade protobuf`

2. Copy `builder.py` from `.../Lib/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal` to another folder on your computer (let's say 'Documents')
3. Install a protobuf version that is compatible with your project (for me 3.19.4)

> `pip install protobuf==3.19.4`

4. Copy `builder.py` from (let's say 'Documents') to `Lib/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal`
5. Run your code

Comment: wow smart solution!

Comment: You just saved my monitor and keyboard. 
I am going through this tutorial (https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#tensorflow-object-detection-api-installation). Finally your solution works!

Comment: protobuf is the worsest software in this world, eveyone rely on it, every version it breaks it's own API.

Comment: what a great solution...

Comment: I had protobuf 3.17.3 in my project and it gave another error after this one, but changing it to 3.19.4 same as you worked well

Comment: This solution is amazing. Helped a lot.

Comment: protobuff ws itself a hack to provide hack across communication and this is next hack, damn

Comment: @NicholasJela just like billion chimps and gimps rely on air to breath, proto is the same for  infra, give it some time and you will get the essence.

Comment: this solution doesn't work for me....anyway, software engineer can not count tricks for solid software, what i can say is protobuf sucks an package management, hope there will be replacement

Comment: How can I solve this? because the package that I need to install is within Databricks cluster.

Comment: There's no builder.py in that folder

Comment: otherwise, you can copy the builder script from [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/python/google/protobuf/internal/builder.py)

Answer (score 35):

You need to upgrade to the latest version of the `protobuf` package:

`pip install --upgrade protobuf`.

The reason is that the Python classes are simplified since Protobuf v3.20.0. Straight from the [release notes](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.20.0) it says:

> Protobuf python generated codes are simplified. Descriptors and
> message classes' definitions are now dynamic created in
> internal/builder.py. Insertion Points for messages classes are
> discarded.

This explains why the generated Python code now refers to a `builder` module, which it cannot find if you haven't updated to the latest version of the `protobuf` package. This is not explained in the release notes, but I verified myself that it works if you upgrade the `protobuf` package.

Answer (score 21):

For some reason, the `builder.py` file is missing from the `protobuf` package created from TensorFlow. A workaround is to simply copy the latest copy of builder.py from the `protobuf` repository into your local drive

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/main/python/google/protobuf/internal/builder.py -O [PROTOBUF_PATH]/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/builder.py
```

Comment: This worked for me with `protobuf 3.19.4` and `onnx 1.12.0`

Comment: This worked for me for protobuf 21.12 and anki 2.1.62

Comment: Nice and simple solution! If your underlying package requires a certain version of protobuf then this is the way to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 10):

Solution with two steps

1. `pip uninstall protobuf`
2. `pip install protobuf==4.21`

Comment: tf currently is not compatible with that version. The working solution is the one with the top score

Comment: Use code formatting for commands

Comment: I catch error with CMD on Windows 11. Your code snippet made streamlit works.

Answer (score 5):

just like Victor answered. When working with tensforflow for somereason when installing protobuf builder.py is missing in the related package.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/main/python/google/protobuf/internal/builder.py

copied and pasted this code and made it into a .py then took that file and pasted it in {your env location}/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/builder.py

and everything has worked.

Comment: Added `RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/main/python/google/protobuf/internal/builder.py > /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/builder.py`

to my dockerfile 

Answer (score 3):

what worked for me:

1. pip uninstall protobuf
2. conda install protobuf

(im using miniconda3)

Comment: It could be helpful if posted the version you installed.

Comment: This worked for me.  While using pip it was downloading version 4.20 and when i did conda install it installed version 3.20.1

Answer (score 2):

Facing the same issue while following the [Object Detection TensorFlow tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) on the "Test Installation" tab.

As mentioned above, dunno why protobuff 3.19.6 does not brings builder.py, so you just have to upgrade to to a higher version (lets say 4.21.1) copy ***builder.py*** and then downgrading to a tensorFlow compatible protobuff (in my case 3.19.6) and paste it. In my case I was using conda so, builder.py file location was:

C:\Users\ **{userX}**\miniconda3\envs\ **{envname}**\Lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal

After that, the test run smoothly =).

Best!

Answer (score 2):

Downgrading protobuf to `3.20` has solved this problem in my case:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall protobuf
pip3 install protobuf==3.20
```

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the issue by not compiling my .proto files with the newest version of the protoc compiler but by using the old version v3.19.4 (see https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

`pip uninstall protobuf`

`pip install protobuf==3.20.3`

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Because descriptor_pb2.py is generated from protoc. So you need to keep the compatibility between your buiding system and running system.

In one word, make sure that your protoc's version is less than or equal to protobuf's version.

FYI, you can download the according protoc directly from "https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases"

Answer (score 0):

Copy file builder.py from where your installing python or if your using ananconda may the builder.py in C:\Users\bachir\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal, copy it then paste to C:\Users\bachir\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal

Answer (score 0):

I use Anaconda Prompt and Environment on Windows 11.

I solved the problem by making the same version of the two Protobuf installs one is the Anaconda Protobuf install, and the other one is that I installed from https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases

In order to make the same version, I reinstall Protobuf releases that are compatible with the Anaconda Protoc installation.

You can see what is your Protobuf with `pip list`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by upgrading the pip version.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

If you are stuck on an old version of Python then you can create a virtual environment with a more recent version and run pip through Python, i.e.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade protobuf
```

or

```
python -m pip uninstall protobuf
python -m pip install protobuf
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably may have installed multiple on your machine especially if you had tried with both conda and pip. You'll be fine with Conda if you uninstall pip. *Vis-a-vis.*

Answer (score 0):

Download the "google==1.9.3" navigate to google/protobuf/internal you will see a builder.py in the first 10 python files copy the builder.py save on Desktop again download the latest google version(3.0.0 in my case )and place the builder.py in the google/protobuf/internal and youre good to go !
(Navigate to venv and activate it first then to the steps if using venv)
You can do this in your cmd as well as vscode terminal or any terminal.

Answer (score -1):

yeah, i use python 3.8.
i saw https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/
and run the example code but it was failed.

there are many causes, i know.
well, no silver bullet! :}

i solved it with upgrade protobuf

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution which apparently has worked for many:

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/10051#issuecomment-1138392640

`pip uninstall protobuf`

`pip install protobuf==3.20.1`