# Getting this error when trying to run a python file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor, tensorflow-lite

Here is the CMD of the issue I run into when I run my python script. I've installed tensorflow with pip, tried to uninstall and reinstall - unsure what else to do.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL1Ej.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71984564/494134

Comment: So that this can actually get indexed by search engines, the error is `ImportError: cannot import name 'builder' from 'google.protobuf.internal'`

Answer (score 0):

its because the does not match with the name or maybe youre entering special characters in the path.

try looking for the path manual:
1.- win+R
2.- Enter → C:/Users/Jake_/
3.- press enter

kind regards

Comment: Weirdly enough, it worked all day until I made a copy of the program to edit some things about 5 minutes ago, and now both programs give me this error.. Even the program that I know for a fact works.. I have no idea what happened? Everything looks the same?

Comment: Oh, maybe you could try reinitializating your coding GUI, and your pc.

Comment: Tried both, weirdly enough one copy of it is working - the other copy isnt running and giving me these errors.. so confusing.