# Object Detection API installation

Tags: tensorflow, installation, pip, package, object-detection-api

I am trying to setup tensorflow object detection, and I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhGq5zvbY3U&t=404s) video.The video refers to [this](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) website.

I have successfully cloned **Tensorflow Garden** and **Coco API**
I have also successfully installed **ProtoBuff** and added it to the path.
For **Object_detection API**,the website says to run `cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .` and `python -m pip install .`

But when I run `python -m pip install .` , I get the following error

```
 _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
  !!

          ********************************************************************************
          The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.

          By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
          or your builds will no longer be supported.

          See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
          ********************************************************************************

  !!
```

What should I do ? I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

1. First, downgrade setup tools using `pip install setuptools==58.2.0`
2. On running `python -m pip install .`, if you get an error while installing Pyyaml, run `pip install pyyaml==5.3.1`
3. On again running `python -m pip install .`, it should run **BUT** you can get this

> pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the
> packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the
> following dependency conflicts.

4. Ignore, the above warnings for now, and go ahead with the tutorial given by the website by running this `python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py`
5. You may get an error saying

> cannot import name 'builder' from 'google.protobuf.internal'

6. To resolve this, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72494013/13940749) answer.
7. Run `python -m pip install .`, instead of installing **Protobuff**.
8. You should still get warnings, Ignore them.
9. Run `python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py`.

Hopefully, this should setup everything, without any issues.